# Data was not insetted error

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am a begginner in php. I tried to do a project where I use ajax with php. I have a div with the id 'forms2' which contains a form with the class 'create' and after I press the button 'Next' in the same div will be displayed the form data, but every time it gives me an error that tells me the data was not entered.

This is my code:

```
 <div class="form" id="forms2">
   <form class="create" action = "" method = "post"><p> Options numbers:</p>
     <input type="text" name = "choice"/><br/>
     <input type="submit" id="next1" name="next" value="Next" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('forms2');"/>
   </form>
 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   function swapContent(cv) {
     var url = "ajax.php";
     $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#forms2").html(data).show();
     });
   }
   //-->
 </script>
```

This is ajax.php:

```
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar == "forms2") {
 if(isset($_POST['choice'])){
    echo '$number = $_POST['choice']';

 }else{
    echo 'Set a number';
 }
}
```

Can someone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here with your single quotes within a single quoted string:

```
echo '$number = $_POST['choice']';
```

Change to:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['choice']);
```

Also you have no `choice` post var, you only have `contentVar`. To get the choice var you could do:

```
 $.post(url, {contentVar: cv, choice : $('#' + cv + ' input[name=choice]').val()} ,function(data) {
```

Comment: What have you corrected? Also check your PHP error log to find the precise error message. Also see my edit.